# How do I use CMake to build an ispc file?

Tags: c, cmake, ispc

I have a simple project. It contains two files:

```
main.c
kernel.ispc
```

(ispc files are source for https://ispc.github.io/)

To manually compile the file I would just use:

```
ispc --target=sse2 kernel.ispc -o kernel.o
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc main.o kernel.o -o my_program
```

So for my cmake file it would look intially look like

```
project(my_program)
add_executable(my_program main.c)
```

but of course it wont link as it's missing symbols that are in kernel.o

So the question is:
How do I get cmake to compile `kernel.ispc` using the `ispc` compiler, and how do I get cmake to then link it into `my_program`?

Comment: What is wrong with [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_custom_command.html)?

Comment: I cannot find an example that shows how to use it for this case. 
1) how do I use custom command to build any ispc file to a .o file?
2) how do I then make the executable depend and use those .o files when linking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I get cmake to compile kernel.ispc using the ispc compiler?

Just use [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_custom_command.html):

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT kernel.o
                   COMMAND ispc --target=sse2 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/kernel.ispc -o kernel.o
                   DEPENDS kernel.ispc)
```

> How do I get cmake to then link it into `my_program`?

From CMake view, `.o` files are just another sources for executable:

```
add_executable(my_program main.c kernel.o)
```

Comment: Yup, that works. Just need to change the command line to: `COMMAND ispc --target=sse2 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}\kernel.ispc -o kernel.o` as it doesn't find the file otherwise.

Comment: Yes, the COMMAND is executed in binary directory, that is why it cannot find file in source directory. I have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but CMAKE 3.19 now has built in support for ISPC.

Comment: Is there any example?

Comment: This is probably the best resource - He points out some issues with 3.19's support for ISPC.  I don't use CMAKE, I use Premake.  But I will ask if anyone else has used the cmake support.  I think we may use it for building the examples in the compiler.

https://risaksson.com/post/1/2022-04-15/ISPC-and-Integrating-ISPC-Into-CMake-Projects

Comment: BTW a faster wat to get ahold of us is to message us on Twitter @ pbruabker or @ ispc_updates.