# How do I include ISPC compiler generated headers in a CMake project?

Tags: c++, cmake, ispc

I am using the ISPC to compile .ispc files and link them to my C++ project using CMake. A quirk of the ISPC is that it generates the header files that are to be included by the C++ code. For ease of building it, all of my ISPC files are in one static library. The core of my C++ code is in a static library that depends on the ISPC library. Finally, my project executable is a separate project, and it links against the core C++ code (this is for unit testing, but that's irrelevant here).

Here is my file structure:

```
src/
 |
 + core/
 |  |
 |  +--CMakeLists.txt
 |  +--core_code.cpp
 |  |
 |  + ispc/
 |    |
 |    +--CmakeLists.txt
 |    +--simd_code.ispc
 | 
 + runner/
    |
    +--CMakeLists.txt
    +--main.cpp
```

The relevant parts of my CMakeLists files are as follows

```
# src/CMakeList.txt
add_subdirectory(core)
add_subdirectory(runner)
```

```
# src/core/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(CoreLib STATIC)
target_sources(CoreLib PUBLIC core_code.cpp)

# Add ISPC dependent code
add_subdirectory(ispc)
target_link_libraries(CoreLib PUBLIC IspcLib)

target_include_directories(CoreLib PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        )
# I believe I need to specify another include dirs here - where the ISPC headers are generated
```

```
# src/core/ispc/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(IspcLib STATIC simd_code.ispc)
# No include dirs or link libs since the ispc code is stand-alone
```

```
# src/runner/CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(ProjectExe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ProjectExe PRIVATE CoreLib)
```

Surprisingly, I am able to build my CoreLib target (core_code.cpp includes `simd_code_ispc.h`, the generated header). Looking at the make file, the include directory it specifies when building the core target is
`C:\\...\MyProject\cmake-build-debug\src\core\ispc\CMakeFiles\IspcLib.dir\\.\`
which sure enough is where ISPC generated the files.
I am not able to build my runner target that depends on core, with an error that the `#include simd_code_ispc.h` is not found.

I know I *could* hard code this directory into my includes, but I'm looking for how I *should* do this; in a way that is not specific to my machine, that still allows me to rearrange my project structure, and will work during build and install time.

I have seen a few examples online that use a custom command (including [this stack exchange post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235410/how-do-i-use-cmake-to-build-an-ispc-file))
but CMake added an ISPC integration in 3.19, so I would far prefer to use it.

Comment: If `IspcLib` library provides header `simd_code_ispc.h` for its users, then this header is its **interface**. So you need to declare the directory, which contains the header, as INTERFACE include directory: `target_include_directories(IspcLib INTERFACE <path/to/dir/with/file/simd_code_ispc.h>)`.